# PIT test says Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT

Tags: java, maven-plugin, mutation-testing, pittesting

I have added mutation test plugin to Springboot app's pom. When I do mvn clean install, build passes but it is taking too long to complete install. Below are the logs and configuration for pit tests. I have same config for other apps and I don't have any issue with the other apps(it doesn't take more than 3-5 minutes)

```
[INFO] Tests run: 34, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- pitest-maven:1.5.2:mutationCoverage (default) @ appName ---
[INFO] Found plugin : Default csv report plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Default xml report plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Default html report plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Static initializer code detector plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Static initializer filter plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Excluded annotations plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Try with resources filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Inlined finally block filter plugin
[INFO] Found plugin : Implicit null check filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Method reference null check filter
[INFO] Found plugin : For each loop filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Enum constructor filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Logging calls filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Infinite for loop filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Long running iterator loop filter
[INFO] Found plugin : For loop counter filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Kotlin junk mutations filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Max mutations per class limit
[INFO] Found plugin : Equals shortcut equivalent mutant filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Trivial return vals equivalence filter
[INFO] Found plugin : Mutant export plugin
[INFO] Found shared classpath plugin : Default mutation engine
[INFO] Found shared classpath plugin : JUnit 5 test framework support
[INFO] Found shared classpath plugin : JUnit plugin
[INFO] Found shared classpath plugin : TestNG plugin
[INFO] Adding org.pitest:pitest-junit5-plugin to SUT classpath
[INFO] Adding org.pitest:pitest to SUT classpath
[INFO] Mutating from C:\dev-workspace\appName\target\classes
8:54:12 AM PIT >> INFO : Verbose logging is disabled. If you encounter a problem, please enable it before reporting an issue.
8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : Sending 22 test classes to minion
8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : Checking environment

8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : Found  28 tests

8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : Dependency analysis reduced number of potential tests by 0

8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 8:54:14 AM PIT >> INFO : 28 tests received

/8:55:13 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 8:55:13 AM PIT >> WARNING : More threads at end of test (14) com.org.xyz.controller.QuestionControllerIT than start. (6)

|8:56:22 AM PIT >> INFO : MINION : 8:56:22 AM PIT >> WARNING : More threads at end of test (27) com.org.xyz.controller.ResponseControllerIT than start. (14)

|8:56:22 AM PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 129 seconds.
8:56:22 AM PIT >> INFO : Incremental analysis reduced number of mutations by 0
8:56:22 AM PIT >> INFO : Created  10 mutation test units
8:57:42 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
8:57:53 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
8:59:01 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
8:59:24 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:00:20 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:00:54 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:01:38 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:02:25 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:02:57 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:03:56 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:04:16 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:05:26 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:13:29 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:13:32 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:14:47 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:15:04 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:16:05 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:16:29 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:17:27 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:17:49 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:18:48 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:20:07 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:21:27 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:22:46 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
9:24:06 AM PIT >> WARNING : Minion exited abnormally due to TIMED_OUT
/================================================================================
-9:25:25 AM PIT >> INFO : Completed in 1872 seconds
- Mutators
================================================================================
> org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.BooleanTrueReturnValsMutator
>> Generated 3 Killed 2 (67%)
> KILLED 2 SURVIVED 1 TIMED_OUT 0 NON_VIABLE 0 
> MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
> NO_COVERAGE 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.EmptyObjectReturnValsMutator
>> Generated 12 Killed 12 (100%)
> KILLED 10 SURVIVED 0 TIMED_OUT 2 NON_VIABLE 0 
> MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
> NO_COVERAGE 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.VoidMethodCallMutator
>> Generated 36 Killed 24 (67%)
> KILLED 6 SURVIVED 12 TIMED_OUT 18 NON_VIABLE 0 
> MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
> NO_COVERAGE 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.NullReturnValsMutator
>> Generated 14 Killed 14 (100%)
> KILLED 11 SURVIVED 0 TIMED_OUT 3 NON_VIABLE 0 
> MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
> NO_COVERAGE 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.MathMutator
>> Generated 2 Killed 0 (0%)
> KILLED 0 SURVIVED 2 TIMED_OUT 0 NON_VIABLE 0 
> MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
> NO_COVERAGE 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.BooleanFalseReturnValsMutator
>> Generated 2 Killed 1 (50%)
> KILLED 1 SURVIVED 1 TIMED_OUT 0 NON_VIABLE 0 
> MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
> NO_COVERAGE 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> org.pitest.mutationtest.engine.gregor.mutators.NegateConditionalsMutator
>> Generated 11 Killed 11 (100%)
> KILLED 9 SURVIVED 0 TIMED_OUT 2 NON_VIABLE 0 
> MEMORY_ERROR 0 NOT_STARTED 0 STARTED 0 RUN_ERROR 0 
> NO_COVERAGE 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
================================================================================
- Timings
================================================================================
> scan classpath : < 1 second
> coverage and dependency analysis : 2 minutes and 9 seconds
> build mutation tests : < 1 second
> run mutation analysis : 29 minutes and 2 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Total  : 31 minutes and 12 seconds
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
================================================================================
- Statistics
================================================================================
>> Generated 80 mutations Killed 64 (80%)
>> Ran 120 tests (1.5 tests per mutation)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ appName ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\dev-workspace\appName\target\appName.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ appName ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ appName ---
[INFO] Installing C:\dev-workspace\appName\target\appName.jar to C:\Users\userId\.m2\repository\com\org\appName\1.0.8-SNAPSHOT\appName-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\dev-workspace\appName\pom.xml to C:\Users\userId\.m2\repository\com\org\appName\1.0.8-SNAPSHOT\appName-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  34:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-15T09:25:28-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>mutationCoverage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <mutationThreshold>0</mutationThreshold>
                    <threads>2</threads>
                    <testPlugin>junit</testPlugin>
                    <outputFormats>
                        <outputFormat>XML</outputFormat>
                        <outputFormat>HTML</outputFormat>
                    </outputFormats>
                   //someClasses for test
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Mutation -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/**IT.java</include>
                        <include>**/**Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```